# How to remove / filter parameter in Typewriter

Tags: typewriter

I have the below script in `Typewriter`

```
$Methods()[
    $name($Parameters[$name$IsNullable: $WriteType][, ]) {}
]
```

...which works fine.

Now I want to check whether my method in c# has a parameter named `commandId` and if so not add it to type script (removing it from `$Parameters`)

This is my method for checking if the parameter's name is commandId;

```
bool IsCommandIdParameter(Parameter p)
{
    return (p.Name == "commandId" && p.Type.Name == "string");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer and I put it here in case somebody else has same issue, you can filter parameters by lambda expressions

```
$Methods()[
    $name($Parameters(p => !IsCommandIdParameter(p))[$name$IsNullable: $WriteType][, ]) {}
]
```